# VBA and json objects

Tags: json, excel, vba, http-post

I want to create meail merge letters to members of a community, reminding them of the new year and to pay their fees. There is a nice API on a server that can create QR-codes that the a phone pay app can read. The server responds to HTTP POST rewuests. This API provides the possibility to pre-fill in the payment parameters like the payment receiver, the amount an a message to the payment receiver.

I am starting from an Excel-sheet that keeps the list of members amongst other items. I can create mail merge letters from this member list, but fails to get the creation of the prefilled QR-codes work correctly.

Since the base is Excel (and Word for the mail merge) the language used is VBA. With the code below i can get response from the server with a prefilled QR-code that contains the recieiver number of the payment:

```
Sub DownloadQRCode(ByVal myURL As String, ByVal LocalFileName As String)
     
Dim msXML As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
Dim myStream As New ADODB.Stream

    msXML.Open "POST", myURL, False
    msXML.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    msXML.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)"
    msXML.send "{""payee"":""987654321""}"
    If msXML.Status = 200 Then
        myStream.Open
        myStream.Type = adTypeBinary
        myStream.Write (msXML.responseBody)
        myStream.SaveToFile LocalFileName, adSaveCreateOverWrite
        myStream.Close
    End If
    Set msXML = Nothing
    Set myStream = Nothing
End Sub
```

If I change the msXML.send statement to

`msXML.send "{""message"":{""value"":""Sven_Svensson"",""editable"":""false""}}"`

I get the response code 400 (Bad request)

The speicification for the message object looks like this[image]

My questions are: Do I use the wrong value in "Content-Type" header or is the json representation of the message object faulty?

SOLVED!

A couple of mistakes from my side:

- Phone/account numbers must be valid in this application
- Booleans must not be quoted
- Numbers must not be quoted
- json uses brackets for arrays, not as outer paranthesis

I have this working fine now

Comment: https://developer.swish.nu/api/qr-codes/v2  - says that "payee" is required: that would explain the error code when you don't include it.  In case of this error "See response message for more details." - did you check that?

Comment: `msXML.send "{""payee"":""987654321"",""message"":{""value"":""Sven_Svensson""}}"`

Comment: '    js = "{""payee"":""987654321""}"
' works fine while 
'    js = "{""payee"":""987654321"",""message"":{""value"":""Sven_Svensson"",""editable"":""true""}}" does not work

Comment: Booleans don’t need quotes, so try not quoting `true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```vb
msXML.send "{""payee"":""987654321"",""message"":{""value"":""Sven_Svensson"",""editable"":true}}"
```

Note booleans in JSON are not quoted.

Answer (score 0):

You used an array ([]) in your message 'msXML.send "{""message"":[{""value"":""Sven_Svensson"",""editable"":""false""}]}"' while message's specification doesn't state it. I guess it should look like 'msXML.send "{""message"":{""value"":""Sven_Svensson"",""editable"":""false""}}"'

Comment: I saw my mistake - your version does not work either, unfortunately

Comment: Can it be "{""payee"":""987654321"",""message"":{""value"":""Sven_Svensson"",""editable"":""false""}"